# Content lock on game bar answer

Tags: support

I've got an answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230120/6434). It refers to the terrible usability of the Win10 game bar. It recently came back up for me because somebody upvoted it.

I wish to edit it to add a simple joke that I thought of whilst I was looking at it. I've done the edit to add the joke, and some terrible person has randomly reverted it without even leaving a comment.

Now my answer is content locked.

I would like:

- My answer to be unlocked
- My joke
- Also if you could bitchslap that guy, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Answers should not contain jokes. Comments can.

Comment: And it wasn't just one guy. Many users rolled back two edits that were pointless/contained profanity. Each rollback was undone, again, by you. We're just doing what we are suppose to; you forced this question to be locked.

Answer (score 5):

It was likely edited to remove the joke because that is superfluous information that's not needed in the answer. While we don't hate fun, editing to add information like that is frowned upon. We'd like answers to be, well, just that. Answer the question as clearly and concisely as possible. The joke was not needed and literally adds nothing to the answer.

It was locked because we had hit an edit war, and we don't want to have those sorts of things happening here. I appreciate the attempt at humor, but also understand that there was no need to continually insist the content be in the answer.

One of the features of Stack Exchange as a network is that anyone can edit other people's responses. This means we can all work together to create awesome content and improve answers/questions, make them clearer, all of that good stuff. So someone saw your joke, realized it added nothing to the post, and edited it out. It's an edit I myself as a moderator would also do, if I were the one that saw it, as the content does not improve the answer in any real way.

Comment: Do we allow profanity? The original rollback war was on removing profanity, and it looks like it was either glossed over, or left in there intentionally.

Comment: @Timelord64 We don't generally, no. It was likely just missed. (We're all just human after all.) I've gone in and edited it out.

Comment: "While we don't hate fun" [Citation Needed]